# Access to html table retrieved with QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qnetworkaccessmanager, qwebpage, qnetworkreply, qwebelement

I want to read the suffix column of the table that I see at http://finance.yahoo.com/exchanges.

I read the page with `QNetworkManager`. storing data in `QNetworkReply *reply`. If I read all the page with `reply->readAll()` I obtain the page, so it's retrieved correctly. I set it inside a `QWebPage` and then I want to retrieve all tables that are inside.

In order to obtain the table I want to use `QWebElement` but I'm not be able to read it. I read all tables at the same level of the one that I want but the `QWebElementCollection` that I obtain is empty.

What I'm doing wrong and that I must do in order to read the table?

```
void getMarketListFromReply(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    std::cout << "Reading page" << std::endl;
    const QString html(reply->readAll()); // html contain the code
    QWebPage page;
    std::cout << "Setting page." << std::endl;
    page.mainFrame()->setHtml(html);
    std::cout << "Retrieving tables" << std::endl;
    QWebElementCollection tables = page.mainFrame()->documentElement().findAll("html body div.screen div.content table");
    const int size = tables.count();  // size it's 0 :-(
    std::cout << "size: " << size << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << tables.at(i).toPlainText().toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dot in `findAll()` selector denotes tag class. However, in your case "screen" and "content" are element ids that can be selected by sharp (#). So, the following selectors should work

```
.findAll("html body div#screen div#content table");
.findAll("#content table");
```

Comment: It does not work yet. I've also tried to use only `.findAll("html")` but the size is always zero...

Comment: @Jepessen I did simple tests without  `QNetworkReply`. The page http://finance.yahoo.com/exchanges is saved to file. So, when I take that document from file both my solutions give `size` 4 as it should be. However, `.findAll("html")` indeed gives the zero size.

Comment: `QWebElementCollection tables = page.mainFrame()->findAllElements("html head");` returns one element, but `QWebElementCollection tables = page.mainFrame()->findAllElements("html body");` returns 0 elements. It's like it does not found the body, but's present in html.

Comment: @Jepessen Some magic. It is normal behavior that "html" is never found, since `findAll` returns child elements matching the given CSS selector and "html" is not a child element. However, for "html body" I see correct result 1. Maybe the HTML docoument that you are using is corrupted.